# Error on running a BAT file using service account. Says parameter value not accepted at this path

Tags: batch-file, command, service-accounts

The parameter value "/user:GLOBAL\svc-prodapp" is not accepted at this path.

Need help in understanding if there is any issue with the syntax.

Below is my BAT File code:

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs /user:GLOBAL\svc-prodapp}"

sc \\ABCDEVSQL002 stop "MSSQLServerOLAPService"
sc \\ABCDEVSQL002 start "MSSQLServerOLAPService"

$timeoutSeconds = 240
```

Comment: Not sure whether the double-double-quotes `""...""` are correct...

Comment: Hi, Issue is with the -Verb RunAs /user:GLOBAL\svc-prodapp.

Comment: I am able to restart my analysis services remotely. But I aslo get the below error message on running my BAT file.

Comment: Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/
user:GLOBAL\svc-prodapp'.
At line:1 char:17
+ & {Start-Process <<<<  PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
-File "J:\CMRM\DoNotRun_Pre-Prod_Analysis_Services_Restart\Batch_Service-Acc.ps
1' -Verb RunAs /user:GLOBAL\svc-prodapp}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterB
   indingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell
   .Commands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: any help is highly appreciated